# Users should see chat messages from other users without having to refresh the screen

Tags: java, ajax

I am creating a web chat application using JSP, Servlets, & HTML.  How do I get one user's to get new messages from other user's without a refresh/reload?

I have tried some AJAX but it is not working correctly.

```
<body>
   <h2>Chat Messages</h2>
    <div class="myBox">
 <table>
  <tr>
<th>user</th>
<th>message</th>
<th>time</th>
  </tr>
    <%  //set the messages into an arraylist
ArrayList <Message> msgs = new ArrayList<Message>();
msgs = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("messages");
String str = "my name";
System.out.println("str is of type " + str.getClass().getName());

System.out.println("Message is of type " + 
      msgs.get(0).getClass().getName());
for(Message mess : msgs)
{
    %>
    <tr class = "container">
    <td><%=mess.getFname() %></td>
    <td><%=mess.getMessage() %></td>
    <td class="time-right"><%=mess.getTime() %></td>
    </tr>
    <%
}
%> 
  </table>
   </div>


/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //get the session
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String chatId;
    //if they do not have a the session for the chat, then set it
    System.out.println(request.getMethod());
    if(request.getMethod() == "GET"){
        System.out.println("Thats a get");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Thats not a get");
    }

    //if they accessed this with a get, meaning they chose it from their chats
    //session.getAttribute("roomID")  == null
    if(request.getMethod() == "GET"){
        chatId =  request.getParameter("room");
        session.setAttribute("roomID",chatId);
        System.out.println("the room is " + chatId);
    }
    //otherwise its just a refresh because they posted a message
    else{
        System.out.println("the room was not null");
        chatId = (String) session.getAttribute("roomID");
        System.out.println("The room id is " + chatId);
    }
    System.out.println("The chat that you are in now is " + chatId);
    ArrayList<Message> msgs = DBmanage.getMessages(chatId);

    //set that array list into the request and forward to the JSP
    request.setAttribute("messages", msgs);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/html/Chatroom.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```

The message gets sent but the to the database but any other users need to refresh before they see any new messages. 
The ajax isn't working, truthfully probably because I am not fully understanding the correct syntax.
I am completely stuck and need this for a school assignment!!!
Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: You need to explain *how* it isn't working

Comment: The message gets sent but the to the database but any other users need to refresh before they see any new messages.

Comment: The ajax isn't working, truthfully probably because I am not fully understanding the correct syntax.